# Open button not there in google play

Tags: android

I just published my first app and when I downloaded it, there is an uninstall button, No open button and no logo has been generated. i have tried looking it up online. But have not been able to find anything helpful. Please help.

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.phoenix.andaz.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/mp3"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phoenix.andaz.AK"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phoenix.andaz.SK"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phoenix.andaz.ShK"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.phoenix.andaz.Player"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: We need more information than this.

Comment: not clear please tell more

Comment: Sorry. I have added my manifest

Comment: android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" -> what's mipmap ?

Comment: mipmap has the app icon in mdpi, hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

No app is going to know how to launch any of your activities. Most are private to your app, and `MainActivity` has a very broken `<intent-filter>`.

Here is my guess as to the manifest entry you should have for that activity:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/mp3"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

This says "either match `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` *or* match `SEND`/`DEFAULT`/one of the MIME types".